# Constructing a second array algorithm

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Given an array x of size n, construct an array y of size n, where `yi = sum(a) - xi.`

How can this be done in O(n) using constant space and without using the subtraction operator? I can't figure this one out. No bitwise operations can be used to mimic subtraction. I know the key here is with the additional constant space by making use of some data structure but how can this be done with the O(n) restriction? Making an array that holds the sums of all combinations except `xi` would require O(n^2).

Comment: Where does the value sum(a) come from?

Comment: Is this a one dimensional array?

Comment: Is unary minus allowed? (Probably not, but one can try)

Comment: is there any restriction on the range of values? keep in mind the number of bits used to store the ints would imply a restricted range.

Comment: @DanielFischer with unary minus this task is too easy.

Comment: @nsinreal Of course, but if the letter of the law doesn't forbid it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, we have array x, and we must make array y. Let's assume that our array x have size 5 (just for example). So let's write values of each element of y' array.

```
y[0] =      + x[1] + x[2] + x[3] + x[4];
y[1] = x[0] +      + x[2] + x[3] + x[4];
y[2] = x[0] + x[1] +      + x[3] + x[4];
y[3] = x[0] + x[1] + x[2]        + x[4];
y[4] = x[0] + x[1] + x[2] + x[3]       ;
```

Do you see this diagonal line? It divides y to left part and right part, where each next element of yLeft is sum of previous yLeft element and some element of x array. The same situation with right part of y (just reversed)

Code, C#:

```
var x = new int[] { 4, 6, 2, 4, -2, 4, 0 };
var y = new int[x.Length];

y[0] = 0;
y[y.Length - 1] = 0;

var curYLeft = 0;
for ( int i = 1; i < x.Length; i++ ) {
    curYLeft += x[i - 1];
    y[i] = curYLeft;
}

var curYRight = 0;
for ( int i = x.Length - 1 - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
    curYRight += x[i + 1];
    y[i] += curYRight;
}

for ( int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++ ) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", x.Sum() - x[i], y[i]);
}
```

Comment: `var y = new int[x.Length];` violates the constant space requirement.

Comment: "Given an array x of size n, **construct** an array y of size n, where yi = sum(a) - xi."

Comment: I took that to mean in place. OP should clarify.

Comment: I'm sorry: I meant constant additional space.

Comment: Subtraction was used in this line: `for ( int i = x.Length - 1 - 1; i >= 0; i-- )`

Comment: Just use reverse iterator from c++

Answer (score 2):

Subtraction is prohibited?
Don't give up!  Be quick-witted!  :-)

```
a-b = log(exp(a)/exp(b))
a-b = a+b*cos(pi)
a-b = sqrt(2*(a^2+b^2))*cos(atan(1)+atan2(b,a))
```